# How to remove elements in a html string

Tags: jquery

```
   <div>
       <span>ABC</span>
        <ul>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
             <span>ABC</span>
             <li>list</li>
        <ul>
        <span>ABC</span>
  </div>
```

This is myString variable, now i want to remove the span elements from this string? So myString will be:

```
   <div>
        <ul>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
        <ul>
  </div>
```

Thanks
(remove() only works on top level elements)

Comment: remove also works elsewhere, check http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
var str = '<div><span>ABC</span><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul><span>ABC</span></div>';
var without_span = $(str).find('span').remove().end();
```

*end() gets the updated string (technically, returns the last selection from the stack, i.e. before find).*

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/t2uNr/

Comment: @Snoob `end` gets the updated string (technically, returns the last selection from the stack, i.e. before `find`). Here is another example of the same solution: http://jsfiddle.net/yhrvN/.

Comment: +1 nice as i thought :) but i didnot think about `end()`  what does it mean

Answer (score 1):

You can Perform a Search using substr function  and remove it manually

Answer (score 1):

A little hard coded but will work.

```
var str = '<div><span>ABC</span><ul><li><li><li></li></ul><span>ABC</span></div>';
stringToReplace='<span>ABC</span>'; /*Enter string to be replaced here*/
var index = str.indexOf(stringToReplace);
        while(index != -1){
            str=str.replace(stringToReplace,'');
            index = str.indexOf(stringToReplace);
        }
alert(str);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dVtCx/

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me....

```
$('div').find('span').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$('ul').find(span:first).remove();
```

I suggest you to assign some class at your UI elements anyway.

Comment: i want to remove all the span element, don't care where they are

Comment: $(document).find(span).remove();

Comment: $('span').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
}